# String Pattern Matching from Lookup Table - Non-Exponential Solution?

Tags: algorithms, recursion, algorithm-analysis, pattern-matching

Given the problem...

> Given a String comprising of non-alhpabetical symbols, and a Lookup
>   Table where a subset of those symbols may equate to a single
>   alphabetical character, output all possible Strings.

...is it possible to compute in polynomial time?  I can only think of exponential solutions similar to...

```
getStrings(String):
  for (i = 0 -> String.length)
    if (String.substring(0->i) in LookupTable)
      String.replaceRange(0->i, LookupTable[String.substring(0->i)])
      getStrings(String.substring(i, String.length)
```

...where we iterate through the string, and each time a match is found in the lookup table, replace with the character in the lookup table and recursively call the method with the new character and the remaining substring.

I don't see how there are overlapping sub-problems that would allow for memoization or dynamic programming, or any other method to reduce the raw number of operations.  Is there something I'm missing?